# Number of recent files in Eclipse > 15?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to have the list of recent files to keep more then 15 files in Eclipse?

Or a plugin that allows me to view more of them?

Comment: Can you specify better what are you asking? Are you asking about File > files, or CTRL + F6?

Comment: @Betlista, i am asking about recent file list in File menu.

Comment: I see. Default is 4 so I was confused about the 15, but this is the max in Window > Preferences > General > Editors. I'm not using this functionality, I prefer CTRL + SHIFT + R (of course if you know the name, at least partially, of the file in WS).

Comment: ok, nice tip about Ctrl+Shift+R, but doesn't work for Remote Systems which i use. I mean sometimes files are not within the project.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download Eclipse source code.
2. Update `org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorHistory.MAX_SIZE` to `99`.
3. Save and compile it.
4. Set variable `RECENT_FILES=99` in file: `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs`
5. Start up Eclipse.